# Twitter clients that use alternative URLs to display/update status

Tags: twitter

I would like to use twitter at my work place where twitter site is totally blocked by the firewall.

We do have many desktop clients like tweetdeck, seesmic etc but each of these would inturn use the same twitter.com/status urls to fetch or update data due to which these desktop clients would also fail to work at my work place.

However the igoogle twittergadget works perfectly fine probably because of two reasons,

1) It would use an alternative url/way to update and fetch tweets instead of using a direct twitter.com/... urls that are blocked by the firewall. The usage of this alternative url/way would probably help in bypassing the firewall as it is not a direct twitter.com/.. url.

2) It would probably use the same twitter.com url but doesn't implement the logic of fetching/updating tweets on the client system, rather when it is done on a different system hosting the twittergadget because of which it is displaying and updating the tweets.

So either ways, I would like to know the list of such twitter apps that would tend to work even if twitter.com is blocked at workplace. Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try twittergadget.com. When you are at home you can set up an account with this site and it authenticates with Twitter. At work, it uses different URL's and you can use/manage your Twitter without actually accessing Twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Proxy.org](http://proxy.org), and visit Twitter via any 1 of over 2000 proxies.

The new version of Twitter may not work on some proxies, just switch to the old version of Twitter. It works for me.